# CSV data set config in jmeter options

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing

I am building a test script in Jmeter for login functionality of my site, so I have provided a CSV file with all the credentials, then I have decided to make each user login and then select a template, In my site there are two templates only and what i want to do, is that i want each user select adifferent template each time, the question is do I need to provide another CSV file for the 2 template only? or is there another way of doing so?.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSV file can have the details like mentioned below:

*username1, password1, templeteid1*
*username2, password2, templeteid2*
*username3, password3, templeteid1*
*username4, password4, templeteid2*

In your ***CSV Data Set Config***, you can set **variable names** as mentioned below:

***username,password,templeteid***

In this way each user will select different template.

hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, this is what I am currently doing.

Comment: Jmeter PrefTest do you mind if I can have your skype contact this is mine ali.hamis